# Two conjugate endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) vector space over the field $K$. Let $f,g \in \operatorname{End}V$. We know that the minimal polynomials of these two endomorphisms are equal, their degree is $n$ and are irreducible into a product of polynomials of positive degrees. Show that there exists $h \in\operatorname{End}V $ such that $fh = hg$

From the class I know that if $\deg \mu_f = n$, then $V$ is $f$-cyclic. Hence, the matrices of the linear maps are of form:
$$[f] = A = X 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0&&&&& a_1 \\
1&&&&& a_2 \\
&1&&&& a_3 \\
&&1&&& a_4 \\
&&&\ddots&&\vdots \\
&&&&1&a_n
 \end{bmatrix} X^{-1}$$

$$[g] = B = Y 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0&&&&& b_1 \\
1&&&&& b_2 \\
&1&&&& b_3 \\
&&1&&& b_4 \\
&&&\ddots&&\vdots \\
&&&&1&b_n
 \end{bmatrix} Y^{-1}$$

But I can't get to show that the last two column vectors are equal, which would finish the solution. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: **Hint:** The last column consists of coefficients from the minimal polynomial (with the sign flipped).

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick, since the minimal polynomials of both these matrices are equal. But I haven't used the irreducibility of the polynomials anywhere out there.

Comment: I think you're implicitly using the fact that the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial coincide.